# Line break in a NiceTabular environment in merged cells

Tags: tables, line-breaking, nicematrix

I'm trying to create a table with NiceTabular, because I had some coloring problems with multicolumn/multirow.

The table looks already good except, that no linebreaks are done in \Block cells. In normal cells the line break works as expected. With multirow I had the same problem, but there I could set again the width as multirow parameter and then linebreak was done, but with NiceTabular I'm not able to do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % nicematrix.sty must be installed

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}[colortbl-like]{|p{1cm}|p{2cm}|Wc{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|} 
    \hline 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Table Title}    &
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Column 1}   &  Column   &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]    {2-2}{Column 3} &  \\ 
    \cline{3-3}       
    &     &     2    &       &   \\ 
    \hline 
    Row 1 & Value 1 & Value 2    & Value 3 & Value 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{780373}]{2-1}{Row 2}  &  
    Long text outside of Block &     
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{548235}]{2-1}{This cell contains a long value}    &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{0070C0}]{2-2}{Value 8} &  \\ 
    \cline{2-2}       
    & Value 6 &  & & \\ 
    \hline 
\end{NiceTabular}   
\end{document}
```

The table should be create automatically from excel at the end, so adding a linebreak just in the text does not solve the problem.
How do I get a linebreak in a NiceTabular \Block?

[image]

Comment: `\Block[fill=[HTML]{548235}]{2-1}{\parbox{3cm}{This cell contains a long value}}`?

Comment: See also [F. Pantigny's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594364/134144): "If you want automatic break lines in the `\Block`, you have to put a `\parbox` in the block (with the right width: maybe this will automated in a further version of `nicematrix`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,colortbl-like]{p{1cm}p{2cm}Wc{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}} 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Table Title}    &
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Column 1}   &  Column   &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]    {2-2}{Column 3} &  \\ 
    &     &     2    &       &   \\ 
    Row 1 & Value 1 & Value 2    & Value 3 & Value 4 \\ 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{780373}]{2-1}{Row 2}  &  
    Long text outside of Block &     
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{548235}]{2-1}{\parbox{3cm}{This cell contains a long value}}    &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{0070C0}]{2-2}{Value 8} &  \\ 
    & Value 6 &  & & \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}   
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Remark: In your case, the key `hvlines` draws all the required rules.

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for your response! parbox solved the problem. I modified Michael Kirker's excel2latexviapython to use nicematrix instead of tabular. https://github.com/Murmele/excel2latexviapython

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.0 of 2021-08-10), the width of the columns with a fixed width (columns of type `p`, `b`, `m` and `X`) is used for the mono-column blocks of that column. So, in your case, you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,colortbl-like]{p{1cm}p{2cm}Wc{3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}} 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Table Title}    &
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-1}{Column 1}   &  Column   &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{FFFF00}]{2-2}{Column 3} &  \\ 
    &     &     2    &       &   \\ 
    Row 1 & Value 1 & Value 2    & Value 3 & Value 4 \\ 
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{780373}]{2-1}{Row 2}  &  
    Long text outside of Block &     
    \Block[fill=[HTML]{548235}]{2-1}{This cell contains a long value}    &   \Block[fill=[HTML]{0070C0}]{2-2}{Value 8} &  \\ 
    & Value 6 &  & & \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}   
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]